# running shell script with html button

Tags: php

I am working with 3 scripts with to goal to command a shell script with an HTML button.

My shell script launch simply 'nautilus', a linux file browser:

```
#!/bin/bash
nautilus
exit 0
```

The PHP script call the shell script like this:

```
<?php
    exec('./test.sh');
?>
```

And at least, my HTML page is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="openApp.sh" value="Open Script">
</body>
</html>
```

The 3 scripts are located in

```
/var/www/html
```

with the rights :

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

What I am doing wrong because it doesn't work !
But when I launch this command:

```
cd /var/www/html
php script.php
```

it call correctly the shell script which launch nautilus.

Do you have an idea of what is wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command from PHP it is executing in a text-only shell so it will not create a visible GUI.
If running through apache/nginx, PHP normally runs as a user called www-data.

You need to determine the username of the user running the graphical display, the display number and the authorization cookie.

See this conversation for more details
[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root](http://%20https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root)

After you have determined the Display. Your test.sh script will look something like this

```
DISPLAY=:0
XAUTHORIZATION=~/.Xauthority 
su username -c "nautilus" # replace username with username of your desktop/graphical user
```

Also be careful not to let outside users run commands on the server with PHP.

Comment: Hi Cobolt, Thanks for your reply and help. But it doesn't work. In fact, when I launch the php command "php openApp.php", the system execute properly the shell script and launch in GUI nautilus. So my question is: How my html page will call the PHP script to launch Nautilus ? May be I am wrong, but I think it is just in the HTML code. Could you help me please ? Many thanks in advance